# How to fetch data from phpmyadmin to table using axios and without using react or vue framework

Tags: javascript, php, html, axios

I'm trying to fetch data from phpmyadmin database and I want to display it using axios, I want a sample code for further undersanding without using react or vue framework, just pure vanilla js html, css and php

Any sample code using vanillla js using axios to display data to table?

Can everyone help me guys?

Comment: Although not directly related to your problem, phpMyAdmin is **not** a database. It is a web application written in PHP to interact with your actual database which will be MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: If you want vanilla JS, consider looking into the browser-native [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: What have you tried and where exactly are you stuck? Using axios stand-alone? Making the request? Receiving the request in PHP? Connecting to the database? Fetching the data? Returning it? Receiving it in JS? Outputting it in a table? Please narrow the question down so we can help you with your specific issue. Right now, a proper answer would require us to write the whole thing for you, which we're not here to do.